# Data Access project dll is not being added to the client bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Hi I am creating new project in visual studio using the following structure:

[image]

Now the way things will be referenced will be using the following structure:

- Client projects will only reference Commercify.Product.Contracts
- Commercify.Products will reference Commercify.Product.Contracts and Commercify.DataAccess.Contracts
- Commercify.DataAccess references Commercify.DataAccess.Contracts
- Infrastructure.Injector will be referenced only in client and will be used for registering dependencies

In startup I am calling the following code:

```
       Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Commercify.DataAccess"));
```

When this code gets executed I get the following exception:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Commercify.DataAccess, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Commercify.DataAccess, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
```

Now I am assuming that this is happening because Visual Studio does not seem to see that Commercify.DataAccess  is actualy needed because its not referenced anywhere in the other projects. I had the exact same problem problem in a project that used csproj type of projects so it is not a dxsproj problem. 
I had solved it by using a post build event.

I would prefer to have a more clean solution to this if there is one.

Can anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading dynamically a DLL, so Visual Studio doesn't has a clue that it needs to be copied.

Or you stick with the post-build events (I am working in an exact case like that and that's the best approach) or you add a reference to the project on the other projects, but it defeats the purpose of loading dynamically an assembly.